# Unable to install grpc binaries

Tags: node.js, azure, grpc

I am trying to run a Node.js app on Azure.

To do that, I need to download all node_modules on my local machine, then copy all of them (along with my app) into Azure.

One of the packages in the project is `grpc`. During the installation, it creates a binary file on my local machine named `node-v57-win32-x64\grpc_node.node`.

When I try to run the app on Azure it crashes because it can't find a file called `node-v46-win32-ia32\grpc_node.node`.

As you can see, there are two differences in those filenames.

I couldn't figure out what `v46` and `v57` stands for. Also, how do I build it for `ia32` while I'm on an `x64` machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that filename, the "v57" and "v46" refer to Node internal version numbers that match up with Node major versions (for the most part). In this particular case, "v46" corresponds to Node 4.x, and "v57" corresponds to Node 8.x. So, you should be able to force the installation of that binary by installing with the following command:

```
npm install --target=4.0.0 --target_arch=ia32
```